# Invalid WSDL URL: on node-soap

Tags: asmx, node-soap

I'm fairly new to web services and I need to consume one from a soap service.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://remoteweb/ws/service1.asmx?wsdl';
var args = {
    id: '2010-xxxxx',
    user: 'aaa',
    pass: 'bbb'
};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    if(err) throw err;
    client.remoteMethod(args, function(err,result){
         console.log(result);
    });
});
```

At first I get `Error: Invalid WSDL URL: http://remoteweb/ws/service1.asmx?wsdl` `Code: 401` and then the Responde Body as the `result`.
If I go to the url `http://remoteweb/ws/service1.asmx?wsdl` everything's fine I get to see the composure of the file and there I confirm that `remoteMethod` awaits those 3 parameters.